# clang 5: std::optional instantiation screws std::is_constructible trait of the parameter type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, stdoptional

A really strange and unexpected behaviour of clang 5 was detected when switching to c++17 and replacing custom `std::optional` solution with the standard one. For some reason, `emplace()` was being disabled due to faulty evaluation of a `std::is_constructible` trait of the parameter class.

Some specific preconditions must be satisfied before it reproduces:

```
#include <optional>

/// Precondition #1: T must be a nested struct
struct Foo
{
    struct Victim
    {
        /// Precondition #2: T must have an aggregate-initializer
        /// for one of its members
        std::size_t value{0};
    };

    /// Precondition #3: std::optional<T> must be instantiated in this scope
    std::optional<Victim> victim;

    bool foo()
    {
        std::optional<Victim> foo;

        // An error
        foo.emplace(); 
        /// Assertion is failed
        static_assert(std::is_constructible<Victim>::value);
    }
};
```

---

Live example on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/HG4WYG)

---

Change any of the preconditions and it compiles as expected. Is there some unknown inconsistency in the standard that makes clang reject this code while being compliant?

As a side note: **GCC 7.1** and **GCC 7.2** have no problem with the above code.

---

Bug report at: [bugs.llvm.org](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35756)

Comment: Could very well be a compiler bug.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I hope so, because it's easier to fix than the standard.

Comment: At its core, yours is a language lawyer question, really. It should be answered as such.

Comment: Check [this](https://godbolt.org/g/PC9T25). It's a simple implementation of the traits involved, which should all be correct in this context. gcc 7.2 has the most verbose error message _"constructor required before non-static data member for 'Foo::Victim::value' has been parsed"_

Comment: It seems like the combination of any default initializer with optional member all nested in a struct is breaking this. ` = 0` instead of {0} on `value` fails as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a compiler bug. From [[class]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#mem-6)

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the class-specifier.

Which means `Victim` is complete at `std::optional<Victim>`, making it no different than any other type in this context.

From [[meta]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/meta#unary.prop-8)

> The predicate condition for a template specialization `is_­constructible<T, Args...>` shall be satisfied if and only if the following variable definition would be well-formed for some invented variable `t`:
>   `T t(declval<Args>()...);`

Which is direct-initializing `t` with arguments of type `Args...`, or if `sizeof...(Args) == 0`, it's value-initializing `t`.

In this case, [value-initializing `t` is  to default-initialize](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#8) `t`, which is valid hence `std::is_constructible_v<Victim>` should be true.

With all that said, compilers seems to be [struggling *a lot*](https://godbolt.org/g/DEkDhT) compiling this.

Comment: From the same paragraph: "Within the class member-specification, the class is regarded as complete within [...] default member initializers (including such things in nested classes)." This seems to imply that the compilers cannot process the default member initializers until they see the closing `}` (and for nested classes, until they see the closing `}` of the enclosing class).

Comment: @cpplearner I believe that refers to the fact that the (enclosing) class is incomplete within its own body, not that its nested classes are incomplete

Comment: My point is, the default member initializers are still token soup (i.e. they are not parsed) within the enclosing class, and initializing the aggregate will need to refer to these default member initializers. This is more obvious outside of SFINAE context: `struct Outer { struct Inner { int x = 4; }; decltype(Inner()) a; };`

Comment: @cpplearner Oh. That's very bad indeed. I can't  find what's explicitly making it illegal though, yet it definitely seems like it should be

Answer (score 3):

Alright, dug up the relevant quotes. The crux of the matter is how `std::is_constructible` should handle `Victim`. The most conclusive authority is C++17 (n4659). First [[meta.unary.prop/8]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/meta.unary.prop#8):

> The predicate condition for a template specialization
>   `is_­constructible<T, Args...>` shall be satisfied if and only if the
>   following variable definition would be well-formed for some invented
>   variable t:
>
> ```
> T t(declval<Args>()...);
> ```
>
> [ Note: **These tokens are never interpreted as a function declaration**.
>    — end note ] Access checking is performed as if in a context
>   unrelated to T and any of the Args. Only the validity of the immediate
>   context of the variable initialization is considered.

The note I highlighted is not normative (on account of being a note), but it coincides with [[temp.variadic]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.variadic#7):

> ... When N is zero, the instantiation of the expansion produces an
>   empty list. Such an instantiation does not alter the syntactic
>   interpretation of the enclosing construct, even in cases where
>   omitting the list entirely would otherwise be ill-formed or would
>   result in an ambiguity in the grammar.

So for the purposes of `is_­constructible`, this `T t();` indeed makes `t` a variable declaration. This initialization is value initialization because [[dcl.init/11]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#11) says as much:

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (),
>   shall be value-initialized.

That means that the trait ends up checking if `Victim` can be value-initialized. Which it may. It's an aggregate, but an implicitly defaulted default c'tor is still defined by the compiler (to support value initialization, obviously).

Long story short. Clang has a bug, you should report it.