# std::optional::emplace() to default construct an optional does not work in clang?

Tags: c++, clang, c++17

I have a construct similar to the following in my code.

```
#include <optional>

struct C {
    struct C2 {
        bool b { false };
    };

    std::optional<C2> oc2;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    C c;
    c.oc2.emplace();    // clang error!
}
```

It's an `std::optional` object inside of a class that I want to initialize via its default constructor. The above code compiles fine in GCC 9. But Clang 9 fails with the following error:

```
% clang++-9 -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp                                                                                                                                                                            
main.cpp:13:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'emplace'
    c.oc2.emplace();
    ~~~~~~^~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/optional:845:2: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_constructible_v<C::C2>' was not satisfied [with _Args = <>]
        emplace(_Args&&... __args)
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/optional:855:2: note: candidate function template not viable: requires at least argument '__il', but no arguments were provided
        emplace(initializer_list<_Up> __il, _Args&&... __args)
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Is this a Clang bug or is there a better way to initialize an optional value in that case?

Comment: Works just fine [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aYzZ8xpNjzkXJ95z)

Comment: I believe the problem is that `C::C2` is not properly defined when you declare the template `std::optional<C::C2>` because `C` is incomplete type. This is kinda nonsense but that's what it is.

Comment: Works for me with either `-stdlib=libc++` or `-stdlib=libstdc++`

Comment: Probably, related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59252363/why-is-my-class-non-default-constructible

Comment: @Evg looks like we need to make that more generic so we can use it as a dupe target.

Comment: This is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974898/clang-5-stdoptional-instantiation-screws-stdis-constructible-trait-of-the-parameter-type , but I'm not sure if the cause is the same.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica very interesting, it works in g++ and not in clang when I try it out in godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/fW3Dgd . If I take out that weird bool initialization in C2 (I didn't think that was legal for a non-const member?), it works fine.

Comment: @parktomatomi I'm pretty sure the code has UB so it is not too surprising.

Comment: Works in clang with `boost::optional<>` so it looks more like a library bug than a compiler bug to me.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Which part of the code do you think has undefined behavior?

Comment: @fschoenm See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59252363/why-is-my-class-non-default-constructible).  `std::optional<C2> oc2;`  gets instantiated immediately before the declaration of `C` and because of that `C2` is not a complete type in that instantiation and `std::optional` does not allow for an incomplete type so you have undefined behavior.